# Uploading screen shots (max dimensions) in Google Play store

Tags: android, google-play

I am currently experiencing difficulty uploading screenshots for an app to google play. Eventhough I have followed the requirements under this  [link](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/1078870?hl=en):  and used a previous design that worked as a template, I receive an error notification when trying to upload.

It says that I have to ensure that my screenshot is a valid picture. Does anyone know what this could mean and have a tip on how to fix it? Is there something that I missed in the requirements?

Simple answers would be appreciated since I'm new to screen and UI design.

Comment: What format is your image?